# Function like pipe(3) but returns FILE *

Tags: c, posix

Is there a function like `int pipe(int pipefd[2])` but that returns `FILE` pointers? I know that I can `FILE * fdopen(int)` both file descriptors and I know I that when I `int fclose(FILE *)` the `FILE` pointers it will close the underlying file descriptors so I don't need to keep track of them, but it'd just be nice to stick entirely with either file descriptors or `FILE` pointers.

```c
int fpipe(FILE * pipes[2]) {
  int result; 
  int pipefd[2];
  FILE * pipe[2];

  if (0 != (result = pipe(pipefd))) {
    return result;
  }

  if (NULL == (pipe[0] = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r"))) {
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    return errno;
  }

  if (NULL == (pipe[1] = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w"))) {
    fclose(pipe[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    return errno;
  }

  pipes[1] = pipe[1];
  pipes[0] = pipe[0];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear you really need `result`; `pipe()` returns `-1` when it fails and sets `errno`.  You might therefore replace `return result;` with `return errno;`.  It's not clear that you need both the `pipe` array in the function and the `pipes` argument to the function.  Also, I don't think you've compiled that code — once you define `FILE *pipe[2];`, you can no longer call the function (system call) `pipe()`.  However, with these issues fixed, that's about as good as it gets.  And no, there is no C or POSIX standard function that does the same job.

Comment: I definitely did not compile that. Was just demonstrating roughly what I was expecting in case the english description was not clear. Probably should have just omitted all the error handling / preserving of inputs until the success case.

Comment: I'd just go with "values in `pipes` array are indeterminate and unusable if the function returns `-1` indicating error", and then return `-1` at all early exits (instead of `errno`).  The POSIX thread functions do provide an alternative model with 0 on success and a positive error number on success, but they don't affect `errno`.  You could avoid that too by saving `errno` on entry and restoring it on exit — and returning 0 on success and the newly found `errno` on failure.  You'd probably make the coding a bit tauter if you did this. But your code is close to what'll be necessary, I believe.

Comment: Note that `FILE` I/O is buffered which can lead to unexpected behavior when using pipes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `fpipe()` function is close to what's needed, and there isn't a standard function to do the same job, so you will need to write something.  The primary reason there isn't such a standard function is that most often you end up forking and then using `dup()` or `dup2()` and finally an `exec*()` function, so there really isn't much benefit to having file streams, most of the time.

As noted in the comments, you need to decide what to return on success and on error, and manage `errno` accordingly.  There are two plausible designs (and precedents for both):

1. The function returns `0` on success and `-1` on failure with the more detailed error information in the `errno` variable (classic function call technique: see `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()`, …).
2. The function returns `0` on success and an error number on failure (without modifying `errno`) — this is the technique used by POSIX threads (`pthreads`) functions.

Both designs leave the `pipes[]` array in an indeterminate state on error.  This is not unreasonable; the argument array should not be pointing at valuable file streams before the call to `fpipe()` because if the call succeeded, the values would be lost.

Remember that no standard C or POSIX library function sets `errno` to zero.
(See POSIX [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html)).

Here are the two designs, selected by the presence or absence of `-DUSE_PTHREAD_COMPATIBLE_DESIGN` on the compiler command line:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern int fpipe(FILE *pipes[2]);  // Should be in a header

#ifndef USE_PTHREAD_COMPATIBLE_DESIGN
// Design 1 - return -1 on failure and set errno
int fpipe(FILE *pipes[2])
{
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) != 0)
        return -1;

    if ((pipes[0] = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((pipes[1] = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fclose(pipes[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

#else

// Design 2 - return error number on failure and don't modify errno
int fpipe(FILE *pipes[2])
{
    int saved_errno = errno;
    int rc = 0;
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd)) != 0)
        rc = errno;
    else if ((pipes[0] = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        rc = errno;
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
    }
    else if ((pipes[1] = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        rc = errno;
        fclose(pipes[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
    return rc;
}

#endif /* USE_PTHREAD_COMPATIBLE_DESIGN */
```

In the first variant of the function, because the bodies of the `if` blocks always end with `return`, there's no need to use `else if` for the next block.  With the second variant, the `if` blocks do not return so the `else if` is important.  C's ability to test the result of assignments is a huge help here.

If you prefer, you can add `if (rc != 0) pipes[0] = pipes[1] = NULL;` before the return in the second variant.  You have to put those assignments in more places in the other design.  In fact, I'd probably set the values to `NULL` on entry and then only reset `pipes[0]` to NULL if it was initialized and `pipes[1]` was not.

Answer (score 1):

The [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) system call gives file descriptors (by filling an array of two of them when it does not fail). You should test against failure of `pipe`.

The [fdopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) function produces a `FILE*` stream from a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

You just need to combine both, as you want.

And there is a [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function (you will use `pclose` instead of `fclose`).

Some systems (but not Linux) have [p2open](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54769/p2open-3gen.html) too.

Comment: Isn't that what the code in the question does?  The `popen()` and `pclose()` functions are somewhat different, though it is probably worth mentioning them.  And `p2open()` and `p2close()` are definitely interesting — though still not quite what the question seems to be asking for (there's no mention of executing another program in this code).